# No video with supported format and MIME type found - Firefox problem

Tags: vue.js, firefox, browser-bugs

I created a simple app with Vuejs which has `<video></video>` element. The video plays just normal in Chrome but in Firefox it shows the message:

> "No video with supported format and MIME type found".

I wanted to ask if this is a bug directly from Firefox or could it be a bug from the Frontend?

If it is a Firefox bug, is there a workaround for a solution?

Searched online and all I could find is that it is a Firefox bug and no solution.

Thank you